# Accessing Element of frame from other frame in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frames

How to access a element of a frame from other frame. For Ex:

Main.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <frameset rows="33%,33%,*">
        <frame class="fra" src="frame1.html"/>
        <frame class="fra" src="frame2.html"/>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

frame1.html:

```
<html>
    <HEAD>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Shift_JIS" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </HEAD>
    <body>
        <b><p id="para"> This is frame one.html </p></b>
    </body>
</html>
```

frame2.html:

```
<html>
    <HEAD>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Shift_JIS" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </HEAD>
    <body>
        <b><p id="para"> This is frame two.html </p></b>
        <button id="but"> Get data </button>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#but").click(function(){
                    alert(window.frames[0].document.getElementById('para'));
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Once the button is clicked from frame2 then I need to get the data of "para" id element which is present in frame1. So, I tried to access the element as showed
below. But it is not worked.

```
    window.frames[0].document.getElementById('para')
```

It shows the error as:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

So, `window.frames[0]` itself undefined
.Can any one help me to solve this?

Comment: Due to security using parent to access parent then other frame the browser will block the action , 

see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

Answer (score 1):

You should put id on your iframes, like "iframe1" and "iframe2".

```
    <frame class="fra" src="frame1.html" id="frame1" />
    <frame class="fra" src="frame2.html" id="frame2" />
```

Then:

```
$(window.parent.document).find("#iframe1").contents().find("#para")
```

should give you access from iframe2 to the element with id "para" in frame one.

$(window.parent.document) will allow you to return from iframe2 to the main document, then find iframe1, then contents() will allow you to go inside iframe1 where you'll be able to find the "#para" element.